# Spring Boot application to have separated multiple property files

Tags: spring-boot

Coming from Play Framework, a handy feature that has helped to organize the application configurations was to use `include`s ([Link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ConfigFile#Includes)) to spilt the various configurations into multiple `.conf` files as below.

`application.conf` Content

```
include "play-http.conf"
include "play-modules.conf"
include "play-i18n.conf"
include "authentication.conf"
include "hbase.conf"
include "custom-caches.conf"
include "custom-filters.conf"

#Any other root level application configurations
```

Is there an equivalent to this in Spring Boot `.properties` files?

Comment: Does "Profile Specific Files" meet your needs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My requirement was simply achieved using the `spring.config.import` ([Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.importing)).

I created multiple property files such as `hbase.properties`, `custom-caches.properties` etc. And then in my `application.properties` imported those additional property files as below.

```
spring.config.import=hbase.properties,custom-caches.properties

#Any other properties in the application.properties file
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use yaml configuration files myself but I think that the configuration is mostly similar. You should take a look at the [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html).

I have defined a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean to use a configuration override file located outside of the jar. Anything that is in the override file will be used instead of the default configuration. Anything that is not in the override file is still retrieved from the default configuration file. I think you can create a similar bean to achieve what you are looking for.

Here's my code:

```
@Bean
static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    var properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("./application.yaml"));
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    return properties;
}
```

For my use case, I only needed to define one properties location, but it is also possible to specify multiple locations:

```
...
properties.setLocations(Resource... locations);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From Spring 2.4, we can create multiple properties file for each profiles as below.

```
application-main1.properties 
application-sub1.properties
application-sub2.properties
```

And then in default **application.properties** file we can group all sub profiles and activate the main profile

```java
spring.profiles.group.main1=sub1,sub2

spring.profiles.active=main1
```

I am not sure if we can group sub profiles under default profile. You can try out

```
spring.profiles.group.default=sub1,sub2
```

This way you don't need to have another file for `main` profile.